# What will be length of array in shared memory?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, shared-memory

I have pointer and shared memory.

```
int *data;
shmid = shmget( IPC_PRIVATE, N * sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );  
data = (int*)shmat( shmid, 0, 0 );
```

And I write array to this shared memory. But when I try to calculate length of that array, I always get 8 bits(or bytes, I don't know). And always when I write to array numbers, I get 8 bits.

Please, help me, and sorry for my English! :)

Comment: No wonder: `sizeof(data)` calculates _the size of a pointer_, which is 8 bytes on your system.

Comment: @ForceBru certainly not bits, sizeof returns in size of char, I think it is 8 bytes so 64 bits

Comment: @ForceBru I know that, but how I can to calculate real length of array in area?

Comment: @АртемТеллур, you allocated `N * sizeof(int)` bytes, that's gonna be the length. But if the array written is smaller, you can't determine its size unless it has a distinct end flag, like `'\0'` in strings.

Comment: @ForceBru but how I can calculate length of array? `N * sizeof()int` calculate size of memory section.

Comment: @АртемТеллур, you can't. A pointer isn't an array, you can advance it as far as you want (until you arrive at a memory location not owned by your process).

Comment: You should prefer POSIX shared memory, see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot calculate in C the used length of some array given by a pointer (because arrays decay into pointers). You need to **explicitly keep that length** elsewhere (e.g. in some other variable, or using some `struct` with both the length and a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

Of course, you need to separate the used length (used for computing) and the allocated size (required at allocation time).

And [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) is computed at *compile-time* (it is constant, except for [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s). For pointers it would always be 8 bytes on my Linux/x86-64 desktop (independently of the allocated size, if any).

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand you!

Answer (score 1):

**sizeof()** operator in `C` is interpreted at **compile time**. In your program, **sizeof** operator return the size of pointer which is depend on your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get size of shared memory then you can use shmctl()

```
shmtctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, shmid_ds_buf)
```

Size for each shared memory segment stored in kernel data structure associated                  with shmid. Size of segment is pointed by `shmid_ds_buf->shm_segsz`

Refer [man shmctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmctl.2.html)